# Command syntax presentation (style)

Tags: verbatim

What is the way to achieve the style for `\pdfbookmark` command syntax as shown below? Is this pure `verb`?

[image]

[Original document](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-1/tb88garcia.pdf)

Comment: There is a mail address given in the original document, perhaps it still works ;-), but in the end it is something like `\verb`, most likely

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, not a bad idea ;). However, I saw similar style in many docs for packages. It shouldn't be that complicated.

Comment: Sorry, I had to reject your edit, because you missed my additions ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, no problem (the right parenthesis was still missing ;)). Last but not least, great job. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked document is from TUGBoat 88 (28.2), so it is very likely that the author used the `ltugboat` class or `ltugboat` package (there are both of them).

A command sequence is being typeset with `\cs{foo}`, the arguments can be typeset with `[\meta{arg}]` or `\tubbraced{\meta{arg}}`, depending on the type of the macro, of course.

`\cs` is defined as:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cs}[1]{{\tt \char`\\#1}}
```

---

```
\documentclass{ltugboat}

\begin{document}
    \cs{pdfbookmark}[\meta{level}]\tubbraced{\meta{text}}\tubbraced{\meta{key}}
\end{document}
```

[image: pdfbookmark]

A similar syntax is provided for example by `ltxdoc.cls`:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\begin{document}

\cs{pdfbookmark}\oarg{level}\marg{text}\marg{key}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please have a look on `holtxdoc.sty` as well...

Answer (score 2):

This copes with any number of arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\syntax}{mO{}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \tl_clear:N \l__belford_syntax_args_tl
  \normalfont\ttfamily
  \token_to_str:N #1
  \keys_set:nn { belford/syntax } { #2 }
  \tl_use:N \l__belford_syntax_args_tl
  \group_end:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\meta}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \normalfont$\langle$\textit{#1}$\rangle$
  \group_end:
 }

\tl_new:N \l__belford_syntax_args_tl
\keys_define:nn { belford/syntax }
 {
  m .code:n = \__belford_syntax_addarg:nnn { \symbol{`\{} } { \symbol{`\}} } { #1 },
  o .code:n = \__belford_syntax_addarg:nnn { [ } { ] } { #1 },
  p .code:n = \__belford_syntax_addparg:nn #1,
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__belford_syntax_addarg:nnn
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__belford_syntax_args_tl { #1 \meta{#3} #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__belford_syntax_addparg:nn
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__belford_syntax_args_tl { ( \meta{#1} , \meta{#2} ) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\pkg}{m}{\textsf{#1}}

\begin{document}

For this \pkg{hyperref} provides
\syntax{\pdfbookmark}[o=level,m=text,m=key]

We also have
\begin{itemize}
\item \syntax{\makebox}[o=width,o=char,m=text]
\item \syntax{\makebox}[p={x}{y},o=char,m=text]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For actual examples you can directly use `\verb`.